# Overflowing Buffers on the Stack

Tags: c, gdb

I'm reading the Shellcoder's handbook and trying to follow along on there simple overflowing buffers on the stack example, but I'm stuck.

I'm running GCC on windows and before a function call instead of pushing on the stack like the book says it should, it just moves the values into registers and then makes the call. The book is running linux I'd assume, does it use a different calling method than windows? How would I get the linux behavior?

Also, when a program accept user input, how do I input data into the program such that it shows in the gdb?

Comment: Try to turn off optimizations.

Comment: I tried: gcc -ggdb function.c -O0 -o function which did not help. How would I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your book is assuming the `cdecl` calling convention on an IA32 platform, but that your compiler is using a different calling convention that puts parameters in registers.  Are you using an AMD64 platform by any chance?  The standard for AMD64 is to put the first `n` arguments in registers and only additional arguments on the stack (Windows only uses four registers for parameters; every other common platform uses six).

More information on calling conventions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

If you add a bunch of additional function parameters before the ones that you care about, you should get the last ones on the stack.  Alternately, if you compile as 32-bit instead of 64-bit, you might get what you're looking for.

Comment: Calling conventions are a property of the microcomputer? The OS?  And when a program accept user input, how do I input data into the program such that it shows in the gdb? Sorry for so many questions. I appreciate the help by the way.

Comment: Calling conventions are affected by many things.  There were many calling conventions in use on IA32.  AMD64 recommends register-based argument passing, but there are two common variants of that in use.  The compiler is ultimately what chooses the calling convention to use, although if you're calling into some other module (such as a library, or making a system call), you need to use a calling convention that's compatible with the other module.

Comment: Compiling as 32-bit seems to work. It does: mov DWORD PTR [esp+0x4], 0x2. I'm guessing your uncertain about the user input question? Thanks btw.